# how would I instantiate a shared_ptr instance variable?

Tags: c++, templates, shared-ptr

In my program, I have the following class `Foo`:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct foo {
    foo(T data) : data(data) {}
    std::shared_ptr<T> data;
};
```

In my `main` function, I instantiate the class with an `int` in the template:

```cpp
int main() {
    foo<int> obj(10);
    std::cout << *obj.data << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the file without instantiating `obj` and printing out `obj.data` in the `main` function, everything runs fine. However, when I include the instantiation part, the compilation fails with the error message `no matching function for call to 'std::shared_ptr<int>::shared_ptr(int&)'`. How would I get rid of this error while still having the memory management given by `shared_ptr`?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `std::make_shared` is [one way](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared)

Comment: The code is trying to assign an `int` parameter to a `shared_ptr` member variable.  Try assigning a `shared_ptr` to the `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr<T>` manages some dynamically-allocated object of type `T`. `std::shared_ptr` doesn't have any constructor to actually create that shared object. So either you need to do that manually or you can use `std::make_shared` instead, e.g.:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo {
    foo(T data) : data(std::make_shared<T>(data)) {}
    std::shared_ptr<T> data;
};
```

`std::make_shared<T>` will create a new object of type `T` with the given arguments forwarded to `T`'s initialization and will return a `shared_ptr<T>` managing that newly created object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had tried doing `std::make_shared(data)` before, but I guess I never tried explicitly stating the template parameter for it.